# Google Sheet data not saved before script copy

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to Google Sheets.  I am trying to execute a simple script.
The first sheet has some data entry fields.
I have then inserted an image and linked a script to that image.

The script performs some basic functionality to select all the data from the data entry sheet and copy it across to a 'history' sheet.

The script appears to be working fine, however, I found that if I change one of the values on the data entry sheet and then immediately click the image to run the script, the last value is not copied across with the updated value, the old value is copied across.

Clearly google sheets is not saving the last edit before executing the script.

I have google around and cannot find a way to force an update prior to the copy.

Is anyone able to advise?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for a bit to let the sheet save itself. As a workaround, you can add Utilities.sleep(milliseconds) before fetching the data in the script which creates a 'pause' in program execution, meaning it does nothing during the number of milliseconds. So, it will give time to the sheet to save itself.

```
    Utilities.sleep(3000);// pause the execution for 3 sec
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, but I have tried this and it makes no difference.  The data to save is not being triggered at all before the script runs.  I have found the issue raised also here, with no solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49657841/apps-script-force-blur-on-editing-cell-to-save-its-content